# Signal analysis in Python - removing outliers from curve

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing

I have the following signal to process ([raw data](https://gist.github.com/louismullie/19bd465b31a2aa2cbca0)):

[image]

I would like to process the signal to eliminate outliers to obtain a "smooth" curve. *Note: I do not want to change any of the actual values, I am only interested in removing spurious points.* A specific requirement is that the curve "wraps around" (i.e. the beginning of the curve should be contiguous with its end). A picture may be more helpful (I have manually traced the black line to illustrate):

[image]

So far, I have tried thresholding the function based on a distance from a moving average, but that failed pretty miserably. I have also tried computing the first derivative and thresholding based on that, which was also unhelpful. Any ideas as to how I can achieve the desired result? I remain convinced there is a relatively simple solution that I am missing here. I am using Python/NumPy/SciPy.

Comment: what, in your mind, defines an outlier? for instance, you skiped some not-so-obvious data around `x = 190`

Comment: I do not have a precise definition - the function corresponds to the contour of a shape inside an image, and the boundary is at times ambiguous.

Comment: I guess the missing first part to my question is "how can we define mathematically what seems to be fairly intuitive from looking at the contour I manually traced?"

Comment: I think your previous definition (maximize points, minimize total length) is a good start. Now all you have to do is write a cost function and optimize it :)

Comment: if your code isn't too long, would you mind including the code that reads in your data file and does the plot?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a rolling median filter from SciPy: < http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.median_filter.html >.

You could also use other forms of a rolling average or rolling order statistic filter.

Comment: Works great - I used a median filter with size = 25 and then did a thresholding based on the difference between the filtered and raw data.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily call it "state of the art", the Mumford-Shah model is actually fairly old and there are too numerous applications of image segmentation for one technique to beat them all.

Comment: `scipy.signal.medfilt` seems more appropriate for 1D data (as in the question):
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.medfilt.html